# Prevent CTRL-V in TDBMemo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, paste, intercept

I am using a `TDBMemo` control in Delphi 7. I would like to prevent the user from pasting in it with <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>.

This solution doesn't work:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if (Key=#22) or (Key=#3) then Key:=#0;   // 22 = [Ctrl+V] / 3 = [Ctrl+C]
end;
```

So, I tried something else:

```
if (Key=#86) then Key := #0; // this is ok, doesnt allow letter v.
```

But when I try:

```
if (Key=#17) AND (Key=#86) then Key := #0; // #17 is supposed to be CTRL value...
```

it doesnt work.

Comment: Actually, it is quite obvious that it doesn't work, because if `Key` is `#17`, then it is impossible for `Key` to be `#86`. Indeed, if you ask the students in a class to raise their hand if their age is 14 and their age is 18, you will find that no one raises their hand. Indeed, if a boy is 14 years old, it is very unlikely that he is 18 years old. Similarly, very few of the 18-year-olds are 14 years old. Hence, we realise that `(Key=#17) AND (Key=#86)` will ALWAYS be the exact same thing as `False`. (Mathematically, A = 17 AND A = 86 IMPLIES 17 = 86, which is always false.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarification. But, still, I cannot figure out why #22 doesnt work... it is supposed to be CTRL-V key combination. Right?  Thanks

Comment: True. (But it is easier to read the code if you write ^V and ^C instead.)

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me in Delphi 10.3. Also, I trust you do know that this trick will only annoy the user; it will not make it impossible for the user to paste text. (For instance, the user can simply choose *Paste* from the context  menu.)

Comment: This is a request from a client. I have already prevented right-click context menu.... The only thing that remains to be prevented is CTRL+V combination. :( thank you for your help

Comment: Have you also disabled the menu button on the keyboard (next to the right Win button)? What about Shift+F10? And even if you disable all these, the user can still use WinSpy++ to send a `WM_PASTE` message to the edit control, or use any other third-party app to set its text from the clipboard. (And a visually impaired user might use a screen reader and vocal commands. Have you disabled its *Paste* command?)

Answer (score 4):

If I am understamding what you want correctly, put this at the top of your unit that uses TDBMemo

```
type

  TDBMemo = Class(DBCtrls.TDbMemo)
    procedure WMPaste(var Message: TMessage); message WM_PASTE;
  end;
```

Then, in the implementation section

```
procedure TDBMemo.WMPaste(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  // do nothing
end;
```

[tbc]If you want this behaviour in more than one unit which includes TDBMemos,  put the code above into a separate unit, then make sure that it appears in the Uses list of any other TDBMemo-containing unit **after** DBCtrls, that way it will take effect in all the units involved.